# How to save a large fractal image with the least possible memory footprint?

Tags: java, image, encoding

I'm currently working on fractals, and when it comes to fractals, detail is a must. However, since I am using Java, I run out of heap space once I get past about 2000x2000px. Yes, I could increase the heap space, but that's not a very elegant solution.

So my question is:
Are there any image formats where I could write the pixel data as I calculate it? If there are multiple, which ones are the easiest to understand? (The Java libraries only support writing whole images at a time, from what I know).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always BMP. You can find multiple simple references to the BMP file format at [wotsit](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=bmp).

Comment: I think I'll probably use this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to accomplish this is to break your image up into small square regions and render each individually.  Then try to recombine the tiles into one large image as per the [suggestions in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412805/how-to-create-a-big-image-file-from-many-tiles-in-java).  The answer involves using [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/) to reassemble the tiles in a streaming fashion rather than loading everything in memory at once.