# Write swing component to large TIFF image using JAI

Tags: java, swing, tiff, jai

I have a large swing component to write to TIFF. The component is too large to load the TIFF in memory, so I either need to make a big BufferedImage which is backed by a disk-based WritableRaster (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412805/how-to-create-a-big-image-file-from-many-tiles-in-java)) or use JAI.

JAI seems like the better answer, aside from the utter confusion of the project.

Given that, can someone outline steps for writing my swing component to a tiled TIFF without running out of Memory?

Image size will be maybe 10000x700

Ideally I would create some sort of disk-based image, and write parts of the component to it, each write being flushed to disk.

**EDIT**

I think I could do this with an ImageWriter, however I'm getting a NoSuchElementException when I call:

```
ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tif").next();
```

I have the jai_code.jar and jai_core.jar jars on my classpath, is there something else I need to do?

**EDIT**
I can create a very large TIFF using JAI, but JAI doesn't support TIFF compression, so the file is 92 MB.

If I install JAI-ImageIO, I can create a compressed TIFF Using an ImageWriter, but only from a Raster or BufferedImage, which I don't have enough memory for.

Is there some way to do a two-step approach, use JAI to create the large TIFF, then compress the large TIFF without loading the whole thing into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to load and store a large tiff (59392x40192px) with JAI. My solution is: TiledImages.

I have used a TiledImage because I need tiles and subimages.
To use the TiledImage efficient you should construct it with your prefered tile size. JAI uses a TileCache so not the whole Image will be in memory, when it's not needed.

To write the TiledImage in a File use the option "writeTiled" (avoid OutOfMemory because it writes tile by tile):

```
public void storeImage(TiledImage img, String filepath) {
    TIFFEncodeParam tep = new TIFFEncodeParam();
    //important to avoid OutOfMemory
    tep.setTileSize(256, 256);
    tep.setWriteTiled(true);
    //fast compression
    tep.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_PACKBITS);
    //write file
    JAI.create("filestore", img, filepath, "TIFF", tep);
}
```

It works fine with images up to 690mb (compressed), for larger images i haven't tested yet.

But if you are working on WinXP 32-bit you may not able to have more as 1280m HeapSpace size, this is still a limit of Java VM.

My TiledImage is build with a IndexedColorModel from my image-source data:

```
//here you create a ColorModel for your Image
ColorModel cm = source.createColorModel();
//then create a compatible SampleModel, with the tilesize
SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(tileWidth,tileHeight);

TiledImage image = new TiledImage(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, 0, sm, cm);
```

Comment: how do you create the TiledImage?

Comment: I've added the TiledImage creation above. I set the samples direct in the image, because i have to load px by px from my source. So i've allways one tile in memory while loading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and I used these steps:

- **Load as BufferedImage** with [JAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging)
- **Resize BufferedImage** size to preferable size (600x600px) maintaining aspect-ratio using [Image#getScaledInstance(int w, int h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
- **Draw image** using [Graphics2d.drawImage(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) method in  [JComponent#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method

That helped me with showing and manipulating TIFF images ~50MB (5000x5000px).

Comment: Thanks, D1i,I'm trying to write a very large image to disk. I cannot create a BufferedImage large enough, because I run out of memory. The final image, I truly want to be 10000 pixels wide.

Comment: I see, then I misunderstood the question ;O. I am looking forward to answer as well then, looks useful.