# Java JAI - creating 1 BIG jpg image from many smaller ones

Tags: java, jpeg, jai, tile

Before you all say 'thats already on here somewhere...' :-)
PLEASE let me say I have looked and not found a simple example of using JAI to tile multiple jpg's and save to disk without java heap errors or other memory problems
I cant find a complete working set of code anywhere - they all seem to be miswritten / unchecked or simply do not work....

Help me Some-BiWan Kenobi - you're my only hope!

Comment: If you're running into memory problems have you considered simply increasing the memory space available to your JVM? I can't imagine you encountering a memory problem if you give it 500Mb or something.

Comment: Do you need to use JAI? It can be done easily without it.

Comment: I suppose not, but I was advised thro other posts... can you give me an idea of how in another way. Remembering that I am creating a large image in excess of 15,000 px square and so am getting into JVM memory heap problems when tryng to create a BufferedImage directly... Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: @glowcoder : I've tried that - still getting memory issues...

Comment: @Sanjay, what is the size of the files? Also, what is the snippet of code that's actually failing? It could be some setup problem.

Comment: The files causing problems will be at least 20,000px x 20,000px. If I create a new BufferedImage wityh these dimensions then I get heap problems even with my JVM maxed out at 1024M

Answer (score 0):

How big are the images? You might be able to just increase the memory allocated to the JVM. If they are huge, then JPG might not be the right format, because you need to load the whole image into memory to compress it and write it out. You might have better luck writing a tiled TIFF, using JAI.

I asked a similar question here: [Write swing component to large TIFF image using JAI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982422/write-swing-component-to-large-tiff-image-using-jai)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I tried increasing jvm to a massive mnumber, but that did not let me create the BufferedImage of the sizes I needed for jpgs. I did not see ANY code examples of how this can be done for very large jpg's. It sounds like from your comment as jpgs cannot be written out without this initial big memory hit first? True? I dont really want to switch to TIFF as this would mean a huge re-write fo my code... ideas?

Comment: 15000px images is roughly 643MB image (3-byte per pixel as 8-bi RGB assumed), so you can need 1,5GB allocated to the JVM (the single images plus the whole image and the JPEG version loaded in memory). This if not feasible in 32-bit JRE in Windows (custom test shows maximum memory available to JVM in Windows using 32-bit JRE is about 1,4-1,5GB), but you can't use 64-bit (x64) JRE as JAI only works with 32-bit JRE. So you are in trouble. Also managing such huge images with JPEG is not adequate. Some projects using very huge images use TIFF or custom formats (Gigapan).