# java color correction on giant image on the fly

Tags: java, image-processing

I have to handle VERY large (1-2GB) Tiff files, and only need to do some RGB manipulations on pixels, where I only make local corrections (color of a modified pixel is only depending on its old values, but not on e.g. neighbor pixels).
Is their (JAVA) a way to read the file as some kind of pixel stream, make adjustments on the RGB values, and write the stuff immediately to another file? I will not have enough memory to store the entire file in RAM (or at least I hope I could avoid it)

Thx for any hints...

THX

-Marco

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/ReadanImagefrominputStream.htm

Comment: Is your tiff a tiled tiff?

Comment: The difficulty of doing this depends very much on the layout and compression of your TIFF. Is it striped? Tiled? Does it vary? What compression? Does it vary? If you have a tiled/striped TIFF with small enough parts, you could probably read/modify a tile at a time (I guess that's what @Leo refers to). If you have an uncompressed TIFF, you could modify the values in place (with some hacks you could even memory-map the file, to allow using the standard 2D API :-)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982422/write-swing-component-to-large-tiff-image-using-jai

Comment: Its not tiled / sometimes its tiled, but then each of them has 1-2GB (tiff files are only valid smaller than 2GB). The compression might vary! Typically its lossless, so I guess runlength encoding might be their often. Typically I have 3 (RGB) or 4 bands (RGBA). to Leo / Stefan Sprenger: Your links are not addressing my question... All of them will finally have all the data at once in RAM

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't actually know what a tiff file is , but if it is a file, which you can store in a BufferedImage, it should be relatively easy.
I would do something like:

```
public BufferedImage correctRGB()
{
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    
    //width and height are the width and height of the original image

    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    
    for(int x = 0; x < b.getHeight(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < b.getWidth(); y++)
        {
            
            //loop through all the pixels in the image ONCE to spare RAM
            
            int pixels = b.getRGB(x, y);
            
            int alpha = (pixels >> 24) &0xff;
            int red = (pixels >> 16) &0xff;
            int green = (pixels >> 8) &0xff;
            int blue = pixels &0xff;
            
            //in here you play around with the values

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, alpha));
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    g.dispose();
    return b;
}
```

you can basically do everything you want with the argb values now.
For example, you could turn the whole image negative by doing `red = 255 - red` and so on.
or turn the whole image into grayscale by doing

```
int average = (red + green + blue) / 3;
g.setColor(new Color(average, average, average, alpha));
```